# Spring MVC: User object bean best practive

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a small Spring MVC application, where a few classes depends on User object.

I'd like to declare it as @Component, so i can access this bean from any place with @Autowired annotation.

```
@Component
public class MyUser implements User {

    // private fields
    // getters and setters

    public void fillByName(String username) {
        userDao.select(username);
    }

}
```

Obviously, User object should be unique for each user. I use Spring Security, so there is username in my SecurityContextHolder, which i can use to initialize User object.

What is the best practice for the initialization? Should i declare it like session scoped bean? Or should i keep it as singleton class and just update all fields for each request? Or maybe i should create a new User object from the Controller class for each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't like idea to have domain object as component.
I would suggest to have MyUser just as class and get this object where needed via UserService (UserDao) which is a component. 
Also it's not a good design when domain object aware about DAO thought.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But should I create User object via UserDao for each request in Controller class? Or I have to store once selected User object in session?

Comment: Saving User in session is a normal practice if your application is not scaled horizontally. Getting object each time from database could be expensive if you are not using caching for DAO layer.

Comment: And, is the Controller class the right place to create my User object?

Comment: If it's about Controller VS DAO then User as an object (new User()) should be created in DAO by populating with data from data storage and controller invokes this method and gets populated User object (please note it's a good practice to have 3 layered approach Controller -> Service (business logic) -> DAO).

If it's about Controller VS Filter  (where to put User in session) then it really depends on your application. Sometime it could be a good idea to have a Filter that checks if user exists in session, if not then gets it and adds to a session

Comment: Ok. Let me сlarify. In my Controller class, I should inject UserDao and MyLogic @Components, then get user instance (User user = UserDao.getUser(username)), pass it through some Logic (String logicResult = MyLogic.do(user)), and finally transfer result to the view. Is that right?

Comment: No. In your controller you do UserService.getUser(). In UserService you do UserDao.getUser() and performs any business logic operations if required.
So controller invokes Service only and service invokes DAO only. You can check this article to get overview of 3 layered architecture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture